# how to show Registered or treadmark symbol in android?

Tags: android

I want to show registered or trademark symbol in android string.I tried using Unicode characters like 
® and @reg; also.But it's not working.Can somebody please tell me how to display these symbols.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

**Add this line in your TextView code**

android:text="\u00AE"

Also try this Ⓡ symbol use ® and trademark ™ symbol ™

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your strings.xml

```
      <string name="registered_symbol">®</string>
```

Comment: i tried doing that string like this:<string name="registered_symbol">&#174;</string>...but i want to show this in list view which has text view in it.

Comment: dont use &#--- just copy the symbol as it is... just copy paste the line i have given

Answer (score 1):

### Variant 1 -- just paste the appropriate character

1. make sure you have the `strings.xml` in correct encoding: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
2. get the character from e.g. here:

   - REGISTERED SIGN: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ae/index.htm
   - TRADE MARK SIGN: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm

### Variant 2 -- use html entities

1. In the linked pages you can also find the corresponding HTML entities `&#174;` and `&#8482;`.
2. you have to set the text as HTML in your code, like this:

   `yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.your_text_entry)));`

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a String in string.xml file like below,

```
<string name="registered">&amp;reg;</string>
```

Now you can access it by calling this String variable.

If you want to do it by html then try this, way

```
String htmlRegistered = "<html><body>My Trade mark is ®</body></html>";
```

Update from your Comment:

```
private String[] m_listImmunisations = new String[] 
{  "<html><body>Hepatitis B (H-B-Vax® II)</body></html>", 
   "<html><body>HPV (Cervarix®)</body></html>", 
   "<html><body>HPV (Gardasil®)</body></html>"
}
```

Comment: private String[] m_listImmunisations = new String[] { "Hepatitis B (H-B-Vax® II)", "HPV (Cervarix®)", "HPV (Gardasil®)",}...I have this string array and i want to set this string array value to text view when i'm setting it to text view the registered symbol not displaying properly

Comment: Can we display it using webview?..when i search for this question i found many ans which says u need to use web view for this..can u tel me ho to use web view for this?/

Comment: @androidDeveloer, first of all clear your requirement. Please dont keep changing your requirement.

Comment: @kedarnath..i'm sorry but i'm trying this for almost 2 days but no luck...so :((..i tried the solution u have mention but its not woring...sorry :((

Comment: @androidDeveloer, No problem. did you tried my updated answer ?

Comment: @androidDeveloer on which compoment, ( EditText,TextView ) you are showing it ? I am going for lunch, Will be back in 30 minutes.

Comment: i have a custom list view which contains text view in it and i'm showing it on text view

Comment: @androidDeveloer, will it be possible for you to send me the relevant code by email ?

Answer (score 0):

Use "\u00AE" to replace that symbol.
To make it on top right corner, you can use SuperscriptSpan like following, replace the startIndex and endIndex with the position of your trademark character. Be careful with the size of the text, you may need some density independent size here probably to make it work on all screens.

```
    Spannable span = new SpannableString(title);
    span.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(null, 0, 60, null, null), (int)startIndex, (int)endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    span.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), (int)startIndex, (int)endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(span);
```